# How to periodically update a database table's column for a million records in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my users' table, I will require to revert the 'daily' column back to the default value '1' on the dot at 12AM.

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('daily')->default('1');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Is there a way where I can revert the value back to default value 1 or update the value to 1 for a million records with no time delay(meaning all the user's 'daily' column will be updated at the same time) at 12AM daily?

Note: The 'daily' column is to determine if user has 'use up' their daily click. User will have 1 chance to click on a button(sort of like a reward box) daily. Once they have clicked on the button, the daily will be updated to '0' and they will not be able to click the button again until the next day.

Comment: Hi @otakuran, you may have a look to laravel jobs (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues), this part of laravel allows you to run periodically a job.

Comment: It is a pity you don't explain what this "daily" column does, but normally you would avoid something like this altogether. It seems like you implemented a feature of your software in the wrong way. Can you tell us what it does?

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware, I've edited my post. The column is to determine if user has used up their daily click. It goes to 0 once they have click on a button. Is there a way where I can implement it differently?

Comment: OK, thanks for that explanation. There are many ways you can solve this problem without having to reset a value at a specific time. For instance, instead of `0` and `1` you could log the time & date they clicked the button. Then when they click again you can check whether they are allowed to click given the recorded time & date of their previous click. That way you will not have to update 1 million records at a specific time.

Comment: Oh wow. I've never thought of that. Your recommended implementation definitely seems more effective. I will try it out. Thank you! @KIKOSoftware

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi @ManojKiranAppathurai, I believe I've already explained what I'm trying to achieve in my post. Anyhow, I've tried Kikosoftware's recommendation and it worked.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I haven't noticed the word ```reward box``` at the last

Comment: Updating the users table daily is Not a feasible way of doing it. Insted you can create new table with ```user_id``` ,```date``` and ```status``` and when the user clicked the button change the value of the record of user for the date.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do the update within a transaction with serialization level of serializable to ensure it's done at once and no other transaction interferes with the update. As for the timing, I do not know how you can get the update done exactly at 00:00. It will either happen before or after midnight no matter what you do. The other solution is to have a time stamp for each row and use a trigger upon update to check if the timestamp is before midnight and if the time is after midnight set the column you want to one on that particular row. This should also be done in a transaction.